# HOw to get Query result with sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below

```
ID      LOCATION    PARENTID
445632  SPND0237    0
521847  SPND0237A   445632
```

I NEED OUTPUT LIKE BELOW

```
ID      LOCATION    PARENT_NAME PARENTID
445632  SPND0237    NULL            0
521847  SPND0237A   SPND0237        445632
```

I am using the below query

```
select a.ID, a.LOCATION, b.LOCATION as PARENT_NAME, a.PARENTID
from table as a
left join table as b on a.PARENTID = b.ID
```

But not getting results.

Comment: Your query is working fine - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7484ea49ab183f82ea495df2f712259c

Comment: Remove the `AS` keywords between the table name and the table alias - they are syntactically invalid in Oracle (but not in other RDBMS). Once you do that then your query works. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=764d38570eede34eb2e25bb4e6b64d5a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #emp (
ID int primary key,
LOCATION varchar(100),
PARENTID int
)
insert into #emp values (445632  ,'SPND0237', 0)
insert into #emp values (521847  ,'SPND0237A', 445632)
--select * from #emp

select a.ID, a.LOCATION, B.LOCATION AS PARENT_NAME, A.PARENTID
from #emp a left join #emp b on A.PARENTID = B.ID
```

your given query works, there is no issue with that

Comment: With my given Query I am getting ora-00906 missing left parenthesis error getting